# Cortana skill card element action is not firing

Tags: botframework, cortana

I have enabled signin card in my BOT framework to redirect to the client application URL and it worked perfectly find in the BOT emulator and from the WEBCHAT. But i have issues in the Cortana channel.

While clicking on the button, instead of opening a default browser with the client application ur, a popup opens and says ***'we cant connect to the service right now. check your network connection or try again'***

Here is my code sample in the BOT framework::

```
public async Task getmypersonalData(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    string convid = _convid;
    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(_serviceURL));
    var replyToConversation = context.MakeMessage();

    // Activity replyToConversation = _activity.CreateReply();
    replyToConversation.Recipient = new ChannelAccount(id: _fromAddess);// _activity.From;
    replyToConversation.Type = "message";

    replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
    CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
    {
        Value = $"{System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppWebSite"]}?conversationid={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(convid)}",
        Type = "signin",
        Title = "Authentication Required"
    };
    cardButtons.Add(plButton);
    SigninCard plCard = new SigninCard("Please login to the application to access this feature", new List<CardAction>() { plButton });
    Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
    replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
    await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do a test using **SigninCard** on my side and I can reproduce same issue with cortana channel. And in [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2959), many developers reported: Sign-In Card workflow not work fine with on the Cortana channel.

Comment: Now, I changed the implementation to use the custom authentication using different configured providers. But, then also it is not working. At least i want to see my custom application login page as dominos skill does